# pipeline to bash in C

Tags: c, pipe

Suppose I have a program, say "master" #0, plus a number of slave programs #1, #2, #3... which work in such a way that #n's output is to be read by #n+1. I get #0 to open a pipeline to bash shell so all the slave programs are set to run in order (C code very much like this):

PROGRAM #0:

```
...
pipe=popen("bash","w");
fprintf(pipe,"./program#1 \n");
fprintf(pipe,"./program#2 \n");
fprintf(pipe,"./program#3 \n");
.
.
.
...
```

Then, since the slaves require way more time to end than the master to execute all the  "fprintfs" commands, how does the computer manage the command line's accumulation? Is there a buffer to be filled? And, if I write down "fflush(pipe)" after every fprintf command, will I guarantee commands to be delivered in the right order to bash? Is this even safe?

Comment: If program #1 is reading from a pipe from program #0, it will block until it is able to read some data. Yes, there is a pipe buffer.  No, the way you are doing it, program #n will not be reading the output of program #n-1

Answer (score 1):

You are simply doing the equivalent of issuing the shell commands

```
% ./program#1
% ./program#2
% ./program#3
```

You aren't redirecting any input or output.

What you seem to want is to use the call

```
popen("bash -c './program#1 | ./program#2 | ./program#3'", "w")
```

(though this looks like something that would be easier done in a shell script than a C program, honestly)

Comment: I'm not sure about the equivalence — but what is going on is certainly not what is wanted, and the `popen()` is more or less plausible, though you could probably just use `FILE *p_write = popen("./program#1 | ./program#2 | ./program#3", "w"0;` instead of adding an extra invocation of `bash`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  No reason for the bash call at all.  Not really a reason for popen() either--he was using it before to feed commands to bash, not to program#1.  I think `system("./program#1 | ./program#2 | ./program#3")` is likely best meeting the need.